# Open Save dialog box after clicking anchor tag for saving pdf or excel file

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am working in Project that are in struts2.0 and I want to save excel report that is generated by the java class(using poi-2.5.1.jar) through save dialog box in specific location.

In my jsp page I have a anchor tag

```
<a href="XLSReport">
<img src="images/Excel.gif" style="border: none;"/></a>
```

XLSReport in my action name that is mapped in struts.xml file

```
<action name="XLSReport" class="com.gst.petl.report.DesignationListXLSReport" method="execute">
      <result name="success" type="redirect">userType.action</result>       
</action>
```

My excel report is creating through java file in a particular location.
I want to open a dialog box like this after clicking anchor tag.

[image]

Java Class is:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.gst.gspf.core.framework.jdbc.JdbcDAOSupport;


public class DesignationListXLSReport extends JdbcDAOSupport{

    HttpServletResponse response = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    DesignationListXLSReport xlsReport = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {
            connection = getConnection();
            String sql = "select * from tab_user_type";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            int currentRow = 1;
            HSSFRow row;

            // Writing Data to ExcelSheet

            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet spreadSheet = wb.createSheet("User Type List");

            row = spreadSheet.createRow(0);

            // This is for Header Style
            HSSFCellStyle headerCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
            headerCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BROWN.index);
            headerCellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            HSSFFont setFont = wb.createFont();
            setFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
            setFont.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
            setFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
            headerCellStyle.setBorderBottom(headerCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            headerCellStyle.setFont(setFont);

            // This is for Data Style
            HSSFCellStyle dataCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
            HSSFFont setDataFont = wb.createFont();
            setDataFont.setColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_BLUE.index);
            dataCellStyle.setBorderBottom(dataCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            dataCellStyle.setFont(setDataFont);

            HSSFCell cell = null;

            spreadSheet.setColumnWidth((short) 0, (short) (256 * 25));
            spreadSheet.setColumnWidth((short) 1, (short) (256 * 25));
            spreadSheet.setColumnWidth((short) 2, (short) (256 * 25));
            spreadSheet.setColumnWidth((short) 3, (short) (256 * 25));
            spreadSheet.setColumnWidth((short) 4, (short) (256 * 25));

            cell = row.createCell((short) 0);
            cell.setCellValue("User Type ID");
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

            cell = row.createCell((short) 1);
            cell.setCellValue("User Type Name");
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

            cell = row.createCell((short) 2);
            cell.setCellValue("User Type Desc");
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

            cell = row.createCell((short) 3);
            cell.setCellValue("Created Date");
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

            cell = row.createCell((short) 4);
            cell.setCellValue("Created By");
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

            List<DesignationListXLSReport> li = new ArrayList<DesignationListXLSReport>();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                xlsReport = new DesignationListXLSReport();

                // create a row in the spreadsheet
                row = spreadSheet.createRow(currentRow++);

                cell = row.createCell((short) 0);
                cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("USER_TYPE_ID"));
                cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);

                cell = row.createCell((short) 1);
                cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("USER_TYPE_NAME"));
                cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);

                cell = row.createCell((short) 2);
                cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("USER_TYPE_DESC"));
                cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);

                cell = row.createCell((short) 3);
                cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("CREATED_DATE"));
                cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);

                cell = row.createCell((short) 4);
                cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("CREATED_BY"));
                cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);

                li.add(xlsReport);
            }

            // Write the output to a file

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("UserType_list.xls");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

            resultSet.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "success";
    }

}
```

Comment: You should trigger a file download, by writing the data of the desired file to download into the response content.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is all on a webserver, you can use .htaccess. Find the .htaccess file (or create it) and add:

```
AddType application/octet-stream xls
// Change the last argument to xlsx if the Excel file is post-2003 MS Office version
```

This will force the browser to interpret the file as a download, which will open the Save As dialog.

Hope this helps. -CE

Comment: It is not on the webserver, now it is static. where should I add ** AddType application/octet-stream xls **